# Unable to login paypal sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am not able to login to payament on paypal sandbox site with existing test accounts. I created 2 new test accounts , one for business and one for personal. Then I updated my business email id in code but when i login with buyer account then error shows

**Currently PayPal accounts in India are only able to send payments. This recipient is not eligible to receive funds.**

I am using url

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
```

How should i solve this ?

Answer (score 3):

for sandbox purpose, I would recommend to create new account using Sandbox->Accounts->Create Account. Note the important part is **to use United States in country**.

Answer (score 0):

I hope your transaction is Personal/Gift. As per RBI rule Indian user cannot transfer money to Indian Users account for Personal/Gift.

Its ok if you accept payment as service. It will charge 3.9% + 0.30$ for every transaction.